# Is FastStrings.pas needed in newer Delphi versions?

Tags: delphi

Recently i upgraded from D2007 to 10.3.3.

I always used the FastStrings unit to do faster string operations like FastReplace, FastPos and so on. The methods on FastStrings unit was WAY faster than the Delphi's one.

Is this still needed on the newer Delphi versions or are the stock methods as faster as the ones on FastStrings ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FastString Alternatives to Delphi XE2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072517/faststring-alternatives-to-delphi-xe2)

Comment: For Win32, most of the FastStrings routines have been included in the RTL.

Comment: For 64-bit solutions, they are implemented in purepascal and not highly optimized. See also [Delphi: fast Pos with 64-bit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20939053/576719)